# Bar and stacked bar charts in one graph morris.js

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, morris.js, stacked-chart

is it possible to put a stacked bar chart and a bar chart in one graph in `morris.js`?
I can create a stacked bar chart by:

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [ 
     {x: '2011 Q1', y: 3, z: 2, a: 3}, 
     {x: '2011 Q2', y: 2, z: null, a: 1}, 
     {x: '2011 Q3', y: 0, z: 2, a: 4}, 
     {x: '2011 Q4', y: 2, z: 4, a: 3} 
   ], 
   xkey: 'x', 
   ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'], 
   labels: ['Opportunity', 'Not Completed', 'Completed'], 
   stacked: true 

});
```

But I want to add an extra unstacked bar next to the stacked column. is it possible?

The idea is to show completed tasks and their measure with uncompleted tasks and the opportunity stacked together.

Thanks here

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to combine a bar chart and another stacked bar chart in same plot

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do it
you should create Morris chart for separate div and by separate element. So put two div On top of each other and make div which is top background-color to transparent.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="ContractorChart" style="z-index:0;position:fixed;width:80%;height:60vh">

        </div>
        <div id="ContractorChart2" style="z-index:100;position:fixed;background-color:transparent;width:80%;height:60vh"> </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

## Scrip Code for Morris Chart

```
    ChartShowLine();
    ChartShowBar();


    function ChartShowLine() {
        $("#FirstElement").empty();

        $(function () {
            new Morris.Line({
                element: 'FirstElement',
                parseTime: false,
                lineWidth: 4,
                trendLine: false,
                pointSize: 2,
                xLabelAngle: 90,
                dataLabels: false,
                resize: true,
                data: [
                     @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
                {
                @*@:{ Week: "@(Convert.ToInt32(item.ContractorsWeek.Replace('W',' ')))", Plan_Cu: "@(item.Plan_Cu)", Plan_We: "@(item.Plan_We)", Prog_Cu: "@(item.Prog_Cu)", Prog_We: "@(item.Prog_We)" },*@
                     @:{ Week: "@(Convert.ToInt32(item.ContractorsWeek.Replace('W',' ')))", Plan_Cu: "@(Math.Round(item.Plan_Cu.Value,2))", Prog_Cu: "@(Math.Round(item.Prog_Cu.Value,2))" },
                }
                ],
                xkey: ['Week'],
                ykeys: ['Plan_Cu', 'Prog_Cu'],
                labels: [['Prog_Cu'], ['Plan_Cu']]
            });

        });
    }

    function ChartShowBar() {
        $("#SecondElement").empty();

        $(function () {
            new Morris.Bar({
                element: 'SecondElement',
                parseTime: false,
                lineWidth: 4,
                trendLine: false,
                pointSize: 2,
                xLabelAngle: 90,
                axes: false,
                grid:false,

                dataLabels: false,
                resize: true,
                data: [
                     @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
                {
                @*@:{ Week: "@(Convert.ToInt32(item.ContractorsWeek.Replace('W',' ')))", Plan_Cu: "@(item.Plan_Cu)", Plan_We: "@(item.Plan_We)", Prog_Cu: "@(item.Prog_Cu)", Prog_We: "@(item.Prog_We)" },*@
            @:{ Week: "@(Convert.ToInt32(item.ContractorsWeek.Replace('W',' ')))", Plan_We: "@(Math.Round(item.Plan_We.Value,2))", Prog_We: "@(Math.Round(item.Prog_We.Value,2))" },
            }
        ],
        xkey: ['Week'],
        ykeys: ['Plan_We', 'Prog_We'],
        labels: [['Prog_We'], ['Plan_We']]
    });

    });
    }


</script>
```